# How to add a character in Django template

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-templates

Django template language has so many features:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs

But I've been having trouble finding one. I have a dictionary in python which is sent to the HTML document.

Dictionary: `hello = {'a':100, 'b':200, 'c':300, etc:etc}`

In the HTML file, if I do this: `{{a}}` the number **100** is outputted.

Now I was wondering, if it is at all possible to use Django templates to add a character for the **100** and all other values. So like a filter that changes the output from **100 200 300 etc** into **10a0 20a0 30a0 etc** or even **1.00 2.00 3.00 etc**. The closest I've found is the add built-in feature `{{ value|add:"2" }}` so `{{ 4|add:"2" }}` would give you **6**.

Thanks for reading this, I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: in general you want to give the template "processed" values, and not do the processing in the template.

Comment: word, the thing is I'm making a small-web store. So all the values have to be represented in cents (in the server and stuff). But for a customer it'd be easier for them to see it in dollars. thx for the comment

Comment: mmo123, you should still re-format your data in the View, not the template. I would suggest adding a method to your model that returns the preformatted value for you, then you can access it as cleanly as anything in the templates.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I will try looping through the dictionary and adding a "." two digits before the end of every number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do this in template, here is what you can try:

```
 {% for d in a|make_list %}{{d}}{%if forloop.counter == 1 %}.{%endif%}{%endfor%}
```

But this is ugly!

I would suggest to write a simple template filter to appropriately transform the value.

For example:

```
# sample filter
def todollars(value):
    val = int(value)
    return "%.2f" % val/100.0
```

in template use it as:

```
{{ a|todollars }}
```

This would give you value as `1.00` when value is `100`.

More help on how to write, register template filters [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).

Comment: +1 for formatting elegance. On rereading *my* code, I can't tell whether I was thinking strings or integers :-(

Comment: thanks, I'll try to write this custom filter. I'll let ya know how it goes.

Comment: thanks for your help! ultimately this method was way too complicated for a noob like me :( . I wasn't able to create the custom filter. But on a brighter note, I found I could store all my values as floating numbers on GAE. Then when my server needs to send off the information to stripe payment, it multiplies the number by 100 :)

Comment: @mrmo123, Curious to find what failed in custom filter?

Comment: I wasn't able to install/register the custom filter properly. I'd always get an error that said "invalid filter: todollars". Most of the documentation available around the web on how to implement a custom django template filter in google app engine was based on webapp. Unfortunately, I just upgraded my web app to webapp2 which, although highly compatible with webapp, ultimately prevented me from getting the filter installed.

Answer (score 2):

> the thing is I'm making a small-web store. So all the values have to be represented in cents (in the server and stuff). But for a customer it'd be easier for them to see it in dollars

Then I think the best compromise would be to [create a filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def dollars(value):
    strng = "%d" % value
    return strng[:-2]+'.'+strng[-2:]
```

and in the template, you can specify

```
{{ a|dollars }}
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try to write this custom filter. I'll let ya know how it goes.

Comment: thanks for your help! ultimately this method was way too complicated for a noob like me :( . I wasn't able to create the custom filter. But on a brighter note, I found I could store all my values as floating numbers on GAE. Then when my server needs to send off the information to stripe payment, it multiplies the number by 100 :)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments above, you really should consider doing this in your Views, or in your Model (this would be my preference for this one).

For example:

In your models

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    price = models.IntegerField(...)   # hundredths of a unit
    ...

    def human_price(self):
        return locale.currency(self.price / 100, grouping=True)
```

In your template:

```
{{ object.human_price }}
```

If your product's price as 1123.14159, then your output would be £1,123.14 (this is in GBP because my locale is 'en_GB.UTF-8', yours may be different.

If you only want the whole portion, you could use:

```
locale.format('%0.0f', self.price / 100, grouping=True)
```

instead, this will return 1,123 in this example.

Read more about locale here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html

Comment: price should be integer or decimal, not float. Otherwise, +1.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This was way too complicated for me though! In the end I decided I'd just save all the prices as floating numbers in the database. When they need to be submitted to Swipe payments, I just multiply them by 100. Probably less than ideal, but I'm not skilled in python enough to understand custom templates. Thanks again.